# Asian Characters on ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, character

I made a file in php with asian characters on ubuntu server and after I saved the file the asian characters are replaced by "?" marks.

How i do solve this problem?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Comment: Hi, check out [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170)

Comment: the encoding of the file is utf-8